# Exit script from inside of try-catch block in Python 3

Tags: python, try-catch, exit

I'm trying to exit a script from inside a `try: except:` block except it just goes on to the exception case.

None of these...

```py
try:
    exit()
except:
    pass()

try:
    quit()
except:
    pass

import sys
try:
    sys.exit()
except:
    pass
```

...exit my script, they just go on to the except case.

How would I exit my script from inside one of these blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these examples raise the `SystemExit` exception and you are catching that exception, a blank `except` clause will catch *all* exceptions.

This is the reason why you should always specify the exception you intend to catch or at least use `except Exception` eg

```
try:
    exit()
except Exception:
    pass

try:
    quit()
except Exception:
    pass

import sys
try:
    sys.exit()
except Exception:
    pass
```

With that change in place, all of you examples will cause your Python app to exit